# Why does line_profiler in python not add up the times correctly?

Tags: python, profiling

I am new to the line_profiler package in python.  Am I reading the result incorrectly, or shouldn't the components in the output below add up to 1.67554 seconds?  Instead, they add up to 3.918 seconds (2426873 microseconds + 1491105 microseconds).  Thanks!

```
# test.py
import numpy as np
def tf():
    arr = np.random.randn(3000,6000)
    np.where(arr>1,arr,np.nan)


import test
%lprun -f test.tf test.tf()

Timer unit: 4.27654e-07 s

File: test.py
Function: tf at line 9
Total time: 1.67554 s

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     9                                           def tf():
    10         1      2426873 2426873.0     61.9      arr = np.random.randn(3000,6000)
    11         1      1491105 1491105.0     38.1      np.where(arr>1,arr,np.nan)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misread the time there; those are *not microseconds*.

From the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler/):

> Time: The total amount of time spent executing the line **in the timer's units**. In the header information before the tables, you will see a line "Timer unit:" **giving the conversion factor to seconds**. It may be different on different systems.

Emphasis mine. Your output shows each *Timer unit* is about 0.428 microseconds. The totals match if you multiply the units with the *Timer unit* value:

```
>>> unit = 4.27654e-07
>>> 2426873 * unit + 1491105 * unit
1.675538963612
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, should have read the docs more closely. Any idea what's behind using "timer units" and not just seconds?  I read the docs again and it doesn't explain.  I would think most ppl think in seconds, not "timer units."